# Firebase random one to one chat

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I want to create random chat room with random search.
I make user's searching value = 1 when they tap "search for users" button

Then when search finishes search returns with another user's UID and creates an chat intent and pushes a message to other UID user to open an intent. But the problem is it gets stuck if the user that I find finds another pal to chat and starts chat first with me.

How can I implement this random 1-1 chat scenario?

EDIT:

I will set searching active user =1 and other user to 2 1 is active searcher and ontent starter user another 2 is passive waiter for 1

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("searching").setValue("1");

FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener(){
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    // Get user information
    Iterator<DataSnapshot> dataSnapshots = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();
    // List<users> users = new ArrayList<>();
    while (dataSnapshots.hasNext()) {
        DataSnapshot dataSnapshotChild = dataSnapshots.next();
        final users user = dataSnapshotChild.getValue(users.class);
        if (!TextUtils.equals(user.uid, FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())) {
            //users.add(user);
            if (TextUtils.equals(user.searching, "1")) {
                // dialog.dismiss();
                String rdomui = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                Log.d(TAG,user.uid.toString());
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("searching").setValue("0");
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(user.uid).child("searching").setValue("0");

                //send intent starter to notification

                //Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, action.class);
                // intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
                // startActivity(intent);
```